# Multiple threads. Doing similar tasks, but need to see their output

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a program which I select the amount of threads and it starts it, but I would like to have control of closing each thread one by one after they have started and see there output of each thread as well.

What is the best approach in this case?

Comment: I believe your question is too broad. Perhaps if you show us some code we could nail down a few interesting suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a user-interface to (a) start some number of threads on a task; (b) provide a way for you to individually notify threads to terminate, using the UI, (c) Select a terminated thread and view its output?  That's a lot for one SO question.

Answer (score 0):

[These](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) methods allow you to fetch results of all tasks, that were submitted to an executor service. And [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) shuts it down.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Hashtable that will contain your threads and have the thread name used as the Key in the hashmap. So whenever you want to perform an operation on your thread you can get its reference from the hashtable and do whatever you want with it.

```
Hashtable<String, Thread> threadTable = new Hashtable<String, Thread>();

Thread t1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
         //Do sttuff
    }
}

Thread t2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
         //Do sttuff
    }
}

threadTable.put("T1", t1);
threadTable.put("T2", t2);
```

Of course this the above is just a simple example. If you take a class and make it extends Thread, you can then add methods to suspend and resume the thread as well as printing out its status.